# The name 'HapticFeedback' does not exist in the current context - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app in which I want to utilise Xamarin.Forms' haptic feedback feature. This feature is currently under preview - so I went to the Microsoft documentation and got it setup as expected.

First of all - in my AssemblyInfo.cs in my Android project I added the following code:

`[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Vibrate)]`

Then I pasted in the following code from Microsoft into my code-behind:

`HapticFeedback.Perform(HapticFeedbackType.Click);`

After adding the code I get the following message:

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open up a new project and under the Android AssemblyInfo.cs add the following code:
   `[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Vibrate)]`
2. Paste in the following code: `HapticFeedback.Perform(HapticFeedbackType.Click);`

Now you should notice that intellisense says that HapticFeedback does not exist in the current context.

**Things I've tried**

1. I tried to update Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials - but it still was not recognised for some reason
2. I tried to close and reopen the solution - but it sitll was not recognised.

I am looking for a solution to this so I can use haptic feedback in my application.

**Image**
[image]

Comment: did you try clicking on "Show Potential Fixes"?

Comment: did you follow the **first** step here?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/haptic-feedback?tabs=android#using-haptic-feedback

Comment: Yes I have a reference to Xamarin.Essentials in my application and it still is not recognising it for some reason - I can assure you I have followed every step

Comment: do you have the using statement for Essentials?  That is not the same thing as having a reference.  What options does "show potential fixes" give you?

Comment: Yes I have the using statement and I have seen the potential fixes and it has not asked me to give a reference I can show you an image

Comment: this appears to be available in the pre-release version of Essentials

Comment: how do I get the pre-release? it's not mentioned in the doc

Comment: click the "pre-release" checkbox in the nuget package dialog

Comment: ok it seems to have worked now thanks @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Xamarin.Essentials: Haptic Feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/haptic-feedback?tabs=android#using-haptic-feedback) is only available in `Xamarin.Essentials` **pre-release** version now.

To get `pre-release` version, check the include prerelease in the right corner:

[image]

Then you can use `HapticFeedback` in your project.

Comment: One problem - it does not even perform haptic feedback at all @Jack Hua - MSFT - how about we save another problem for another day? Thanks for the answer.